# Reconciling two definitions of 'uncorrelatedness'

Tags: mathematical-statistics

[In this paper](http://terpconnect.umd.edu/~bmomen/BIOM621/LineardepCorrOrthogonal.pdf), the authors defined uncorrelatedness in the following way:

Let $\mathbf{X}=(X_1,...,X_n)$, and $\mathbf{Y}=(Y_1,...,Y_n)$, where $X_i\sim X$ and $Y_i\sim Y$.

$\mathbf{X},\mathbf{Y}$ are uncorrelated iff $(\mathbf{X}-\bar{X}\mathbf{1})'(\mathbf{Y}-\bar{Y}\mathbf{1})=0$, where $\bar{X}=1/n \sum X_i$ and $\mathbf{1}=(1,...,1)$.

My question is what is the link between this definition of uncorrelatedness and the one usually used (I think), that of (for vectors r.v.) covariance matrix -  a matrix where each entry $(i,j)$ is $\text{Corr}(X_i,X_j)$ - being an identity matrix?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like the thing they're computing is a multiple of a sample correlation. If those terms are zero, the off-diagonal elements of the sample correlation matrix will be 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authors in the specific paper do not treat the case of *statistical* correlation and non-correlation, which is only defined in terms of *expected values*. They are interested in vectors of *realizations* of two random variables, and the conditions they define are with respect to specific vectors, not the r.v.'s in general. And they *explicitly say so* in the Introduction of the paper.

Their interest lies in providing geometric intuition and conceptual separation about the three concepts of linear dependence, orthogonality and uncorrelatedness, in a linear algebra context, not a statistical one. So their definitions are suited to this view of these concepts, rather than the statistical ones.

Note how much more *strict* is this condition for uncorrelatedness of vectors of numbers, compared to the conditions for statistical uncorrelatedness: the later requires only that the condition $(\mathbf{X}-\bar{X}\mathbf{1})'(\mathbf{Y}-\bar{Y}\mathbf{1})=0$ holds "on average"

Comment: Thanks for your interest in this question Alecos. One doubt: Could you elaborate a bit further on the last part of your answer? How does the statistical definition, $E[(\mathbf{X}-E(\mathbf{X}))(\mathbf{Y}-E(\mathbf{Y}))']= I_n$ relate to $E[(\mathbf{X}-E(\mathbf{X}))'(\mathbf{Y}-E(\mathbf{Y}))]=0$? And what is the link with orthogonality in the econometric sense? I hope you don't mind. (Your profile said you're doing a macro phd, so I have to take advantage. :) )

Comment: I have the impression that you are confusing  $E[(\mathbf{X}-E(\mathbf{X}))(\mathbf{Y}-E(\mathbf{Y}))']$ with $E[(\mathbf{X}-E(\mathbf{X}))(\mathbf{X}-E(\mathbf{X}))']$. Moreover this (last) expression gives covariance of the elements of vector $\mathbf X$, not correlation, so it is not equal to the identity matrix -what we want for non-correlation is that it is diagonal.

Comment: Yes, you're right, my mistake...  The papers def. is the usual def of sample covariance = 0 (without the constant 1/(n-1)). 

But still, how come in many econometric texts it seems as if they use the definition of orthogonality as interchangeable with uncorrelatedness? (maybe I'm just confusing things... I I have already asked something similar before, but I didn't understand some of the comments, nor did I get an answer. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111391/interpreting-orthogonality )

Comment: I posted an answer there.